# Finding Area Under the Curve (AUC) in R by Trapezoidal Rule

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a below mentioned Sample List containing Data Frames (Each in has ...ID,yobs,x(independent variable)).And I want to find AUC(Trapezoidal rule)for each case(ID).., 
So that my output(master data frame) looks like following (have shown at last)

Can anybody suggest the efficient way of finding this (I have a high number of rows for each ID's)

Thank you

```
#Some Make up code for only one data frame
Y1=c(0,2,5,7,9)
Y2=c(0,1,3,8,11)
Y3=c(0,4,8,9,12,14,18) 
t1=c(0:4)
t2=c(0:4)
t3=c(0:6) 

a1=data.frame(ID=1,y=Y1,x=t1) 
a2=data.frame(ID=2,y=Y2,x=t2) 
a3=data.frame(ID=3,y=Y3,x=t3) 
data=rbind(a1,a2,a3) 

#dataA(Just to show)
   ID  obs time 
1   1  0   0 
2   1  2   1 
3   1  5   2 
4   1  7   3 
5   1  9   4 
6   2  0   0 
7   2  1   1 
8   2  3   2 
9   2  8   3 
10  2 11   4 
11  3  0   0 
12  3  4   1 
13  3  8   2 
14  3  9   3 
15  3 12   4 
16  3 14   5 
17  3 18   6 

 #dataB(Just to show)
   ID  obs time 
1   1  0   0 
2   1  2   1 
3   1  5   2 
4   1  7   3 
5   1  9   4 
6   2  0   0 
7   2  1   1 
8   2  3   2 

  #dataC(Just to show)
   ID  obs time 
1   1  0   0 
2   1  2   1 
3   1  5   2 
4   1  7   3 
5   1  9   4 
6   2  0   0 
7   2  1   1 
8   2  3   2 

##Desired output

      ID  AUC
dataA  1   XX
dataA  2   XX
dataA  3   XX
dataB  1   XX
dataB  2   XX
dataC  1   XX
dataC  2   XX
```

Comment: Try [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Integration+in+r&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#q=trapezoidal+integration+in+r&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing something like this would work

```
calcauc<-function(data) {
    psum<-function(x) rowSums(embed(x,2))
    stack(lapply(split(data, data$ID), function(z) 
        with(z, sum(psum(y) * diff(x)/ 2)))
    )
}
calcauc(data)

#   values ind
# 1   18.5   1
# 2   17.5   2
# 3   56.0   3
```

Of course normally `x` and `y` values are between 0 and 1 for ROC curves which is why we seem to have such large "AUC" values but really this is just the area of the polygon underneath the line defined by the points in the data set.

The `psum` function is just a helper function to calculate pair-wise sums (useful in the formula for the area of trapezoid).

Basically we use `split()` to look at one ID at a time, then we calculate the area for each ID, then we use `stack()` to bring everything back into one data.frame.

Comment: @MrFlick...If i want to apply the same to more than one data frame(for e.g.here "data" is a data frame...now i have list of 5 different "data" and i want to apply same function.

Comment: @nopainnogain I updated to make it a reusable function

Comment: let me try that function to list of 4-5 data frames..and i will update you soon

Comment: for some reason it is not working ...can you please guide me in it...i have edited the question

Comment: This is really outside the scope of the original question. The function still only works with one data set a time. You may combine the results for multiple data.frames via `rbind()` and maybe `cbind()` to add a column indicating source. But the comments are not a good place to bring up new questions as the ability to answer them is greatly limited.

Comment: Appologies for that.I Tried to Repost the question again !!Please take a look.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here are two other ways. The first uses `integrate(...)` on a function defined by the linear interpolation between the points. The second uses the `trapz(...)` function described in the comment from @nrussel.

```
f <- function(x,df) approxfun(df)(x)
sapply(split(data,data$ID),function(df)c(integrate(f,min(df$x),max(df$x),df[3:2])$value))
#    1    2    3 
# 18.5 17.5 56.0 

library(caTools)
sapply(split(data,data$ID),function(df) trapz(df$x,df$y))
#    1    2    3 
# 18.5 17.5 56.0
```